# Выборка JQuery

Tags: jquery

Как JQuery можно сказать выбрать ту картинку, на которую наведена (нажата) мышка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("img").click(function(){//Это клик
    $(this).doSomeThing();
});
$("img").mouseover();//наведение
```

Всё это есть в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)